# access elements inside an frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code is below

I need to access input elements in b.html. Please provide me javascript suggestions. i am getting error while trying through chrome console

FIRST ATTEMPT:

```
   document.getElementsByName['body'].contentDocument
```

VM331:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentDocument' of undefined

```
   document.getElementsByName['body'].contentWindow.document
```

VM347:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of undefined

2nd ATTEMPT:

```
  var theFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[2];
  var theFrameDocument = theFrame.contentWindow.document;
  var button = theFrameDocument.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

VM494:3 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from   accessing a cross-origin frame.

main.html

```
    <html>
    <frameset framepadding="0" framespacing="0" bgcolor="#F0E68C" border="0" frameborder="no">
    <frameset rows="16%,*">
    <frame bgcolor="white"  src="h.html" name="header" marginwidth="15" marginheight="40" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" noresize="" width="100%">
    <frameset bordercolor="#F0E68C" cols="200px,*">
    <frame src="l.html" name="left"/>
    <frame src="b.html" id="body1" name="body"/>
    </frameset>
    </frameset>
    <noframes>
    &amp;lt;BODY&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;/BODY&amp;gt;
    </noframes> 
    </frameset>
    </html>
```

h.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    header
    </body>
    </html>
```

l.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    left
    </body>
    </html>
```

b.html

```
    <html>
    <body>
    body
    <input id="input1" value="empty" type="text" name="txtProdCoating" size="25">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: For obvious security reasons you cannot - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security restrictions prevent access to other files from documents served via `file://`.

Run a web server and load the documents over HTTP instead.